# why does my raspberrypi 3B not able to reboot each time power is shut down?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, linux, putty, xming

I installed raspberian in my **raspberrypi**. It worked for the first time. But when I shut it down, it didn't reboot again. So, I had to format the sdcard and reinstall the raspberian again. And unluckily this happens every time I shut the power down.

Comment: How do you shut the power down?

Comment: Do you keep the sdcard in the sd-port? And are you able to write to that sdcard?

Comment: yes, I can write

Comment: When the Pi is shut down, you are unplugging the power supply, right? And when you want it to turn on again, you are plugging in the power supply, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try jumping GPIO PIN 5 to GND PIN with a bit of wire, only momentarily, you could use a switch in the future to make it easier. This should boot up the pi after shutdown.

If it powers up but doesn't boot into the OS, try reading the image in Win32DiskImager or similar and compare it to a fresh image that you know will work and see what's different or if the old one is corrupted.

Comment: won't there be short circuit if I do this??

Comment: That's what its designed to do, you created a short circuit, pulling PIN 5 to ground. When its off this triggers a wakeup, much like on your computer the switch on the front is just shorting two pins on the motherboard behind it. https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi this is a tutorial on wiring a switch to power it on, its the same principal but more permanent, touching a wire briefly between the two does the same thing :)